# How do I find the time elapsed from a given point in a parabollic trajectory until the impact to the ground?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> The diagram from below shows a projectile being fired from the origin
>   of coordinates. It is known that it takes $t$ seconds to impact the
>   ground at a given range $R$. Find the time that it takes from point
>   $A$ to the point of impact in $R$. Assume $g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&0.60t\\
2.&0.65t\\
3.&0.70t\\
4.&0.85t\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly on how to manipulate the equations for a parabollic trajectory.

In this given situation it can be established that the vertex is at $H,\frac{R}{2}$.

Thus the equation for the parabola would be as follows:

$y=-a\left(x-\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+H$

Since the points in the trajectory which are known are $(0,0)$ and $(R,0)$ it can be known the value of a:

$0=-a\left(0-\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+H$

$a=\frac{4H}{R^2}$

Then:

$y=-\frac{4H}{R^2}\left(x-\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+H$

Therefore when the $\frac{H}{2}$ then $x$ would be:

$\frac{H}{2}=-\frac{4H}{R^2}\left(x-\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+H$

$x=-\frac{1}{4}\left(-2 + \sqrt 2\right) R$

$x=\frac{1}{4}\left(2 + \sqrt 2\right) R$

Since in the graph it is observed that the range is in the first quadrant then I'm discarding the negative value, and it becomes reduced to:

$x=\frac{1}{4}\left(2 + \sqrt 2\right) R$

Which should be value of $R$.

But then this is where I'm stuck, how am I supposed to get the time elapsed from this equation?. Can somebody help me here?.

The only equations which I recall are:

$y=v_o\sin\omega t -\frac{1}{2}gt^2$

$x=v_o \cos\omega t$

But that's where I'm still stuck. Can someone indicate me what sort of algebraic manipulation should I do to obtain the requested time?.

Comment: What is the point $A$ ?

Comment: @EmilioNovati I'm sorry the point A should had been where $\frac{H}{2}$ is at. I'm going to update this image to reflect that correction, but I believe given this information. Can the problem be solved?.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I have already updated the statement missing in the drawing. I think it can be solved now. At least this is the way how it was this problem.

Comment: Those last two equations are most certainly not a parameterization of a parabola. You can see this for yourself: the $x$ coordinate oscillates back and forth between $-v_0$ and $v_0$ instead of increasing steadily with time.

Comment: Two points: there are two solutions for x at $y=H/2$ and they are both positive (because $2 - \sqrt{2} \gt 0$): they correspond to the intersection of the line $y=H/2$ with the parabola. The smaller one is the x-coord of A; the larger is the other point - so you discarded the correct value and kept the wrong one. The second point is that the velocity in the x-direction is constant (no force in that direction, hence no acceleration, hence constant velocity).Therefore, since $x=v_x t$, you can calculate the ratio of the times as the ratio of the x-distances which you know.

Answer (score 1):

*I renamed the time to reach the point $R$ as $tf$, to avoid confusion with the time variable $t$.

The velocities along the two axes are:
\begin{cases}
v_y = -gt + v_y(0)t\\
v_x = constant = \frac{R}{t_f}.
\end{cases}

The motion is described by the following equations:
\begin{cases}
y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_y(0)t\\
x(t)=v_xt
\end{cases}

Describing a point as: $P(t,y)$, the point A corresponds to: $A(t_a, \frac{H}{2})$.

Note that there will be two different points with height $\frac{H}{2}$, but A is the time with the smaller time value.

Focusing on the $y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_y(0)t$,
we know that $y(t)$ intersect the poins $(0,0), (H,\frac{t_f}{2}), (0, t_f).$

Using the third listed above we find the equation:
$0 = \frac{g}{2}t_f^2 + v_y(0)t_f$.

Solving for $t_f$ we find:

$ t_f=\frac{2v_y(0)}{g}, v_y(0)=\frac{gt_f}{2} $.

We rewrite $y(t)$:
$y(t)=-\frac{g}{2}t^2 + \frac{gt_f}{2}t = \frac{gt}{2}(t_f-t).$

Now we want to find the time $t_a$ where $t_a$ is the time where (for the first time):
 $y(t)=\frac{H}{2}$.

Using the point $(H,\frac{t_f}{2})$ we find $H$ to be:
$H=\frac{gt_f^2}{8}$.

Solving the system:
\begin{cases}
y(\frac{H}{2})=\frac{gt}{2}(t_f-t)\\
H=\frac{gt_f^2}{8}
\end{cases}
we find $t_a$ to be equals to $0,15t$.

So finally we determine the time to go from point A to point R, $t_{AR}$:
$t_{AR}=t_f-t_a=t_f-0.15t_f=0.85t_f$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can split the motion. You can see the problem as the projectile drop from H to 0 and drop from H to H/2.

So the t equals to sqrt(2H/g)+sqrt(H/g)

Comment: All the answers are given as a function of $t$ not from $H$. I think the indended meaning is to find the time which will it take to drop from $\frac{H}{2}$ with respect of the total time. What would be the procedure then?.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The motion is described by the equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
y=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_yt\\
x=v_xt
\end{cases}
$$
Use the known points: $(0,0), (R,0), (R/2,H)$ to find $v_x$ and $v_y$, then you can find the time needed to go tot the point $A$... and solve the problem.

Comment: One of my major confusions was to use or not to use the launch angle?. In your system of equations you're **not** using the launch angle to get the time. Can you explain this fact?. Is it unneeded or what?.

Comment: I think this approach is way too algebraic. But I'm stuck at expressions which depend from $R$ and $H$. From then what?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Launch angle is implicit in the components of the launch velocity. I don’t see any pressing need to compute that angle directly since you’re eventually going to need those components, anyway, and not the angle itself.

Comment: @amd Okay I got that part. But I'm left with an expression which depends from the range and height but not the time as the answers are expressed. I'm confused exactly how am I supposed to use $(0,0)$ if in the equation depending of the trajectory both sides null?. I'm still stuck on this one.

Comment: @EmilioNovati. Just in case I've obtained $v_x=4\sqrt{\frac{5}{4H}}$ and $v_y=R\sqrt{\frac{5}{4H}}$. But that's how far I went on this.

Comment: Please edit your question. Is the projectile  fired from A or the origin?